# I can not change the name of my opacity.Its change.Its change?

Tags: xtk

Would anyone know how to change the name of the menu opacity to a name of my choice in Slice?

Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the .name function of dat.gui.

```
gui.add(volume, 'opacity').name('Transparency');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, user1563788 ! Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's a dat.gui question and not really related to XTK. Basically you have to create a wrapper object:

```
var settings = {

  transparency: 1.0

}
```

`transparency` would be your new name.

Then, you define the controller using the settings object

```
var opacityController = lhgui.add(settings, 'transparency', 0, 1);
```

And in the callback, adjust the XTK opacity value:

```
opacityController.onChange(function() {

  mesh.opacity = settings.transparency;

});
```